# Find the matching elements in more than two lists

Tags: python

How can one easily find the common values between more than two lists?

Exemple:

Lists to match:

```
L1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
L2 = [4,5,6,7,8]
L3 = [9,10,11,12,4]
L4 = [13,10,12,4]
```

Would return:

```
L5 = [4]
```

Note: something like the following code would take far too long:

```
def search(a,b,c,d):                          
    my_list=[]
    for i in a:
        for i in b:
            for i in c: 
                for i in d:
                    if i in a and i in b and i in c and i in d: 
                        id_sel.append(i)
return (my_list)
```

Note: something like the following code would be appreciated:

```
my_list=list(set(a).intersection(b))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`set.intersection()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection):

```
>>> set(L1).intersection(L2, L3, L4)
set([4])
#or
>>> set.intersection(set(L1), L2, L3, L4)
set([4])
```